Pimcore 6.9 workflow PHI API
Hello!
In the pimcore command class, I’m trying to change the state of the product and I’m getting an error:
In GuardListener.php line 86:
There are no tokens available for workflow “product”.
What is this caused by? Why are there no tokens? Should I log in a user, or maybe create a controller that will move the product to the right state after hitting it? I have no idea.
Would logging in a user in the code help? I will also try to create a controller that handles this type of events (object transitions in workflow) and call it via API in the command line, will that help?
